# Finding the definite integral, result involving exponential integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function

I am finding the integral:

$$
\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}tw}}{w-2\mathrm{i}} dw
$$

where $i$ is imaginary number.

I know how to come up with the integration result, which is $e^{-2t}Ei(itw+2t)+C$. However I am stuck when thinking about definite integral and the infinity property of [Exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).

The online calculator show that the definite integral value is $2\mathrm{i}{\pi}\mathrm{e}^{-2t}$.

I checked that [Limit to Infinity of Exponential Integral Function](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Limit_to_Infinity_of_Exponential_Integral_Function), which show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }Ei(x)=0$. Therefore, the when I substitute $+\infty
$ to $w$ above, the first part should be $0
$. How do we deal with the $-\infty$ part?

Comment: What are the bounds for $t$?

Comment: The above integral is actually part of the process finding the inverse Fourier transform of some function, it is just like $e^{jwt}$.

Answer (score 2):

One way is by complex analysis. Creating a closed contour consisting of two parts, one ($\gamma_1$) from $-R$ to $R$ and a second ($\gamma_2$) being the semicircle from $R$ to $-R$ centered at $0$. Letting

$f(z) = e^{itz} / (z-2i)$

one has that the only pole is at $z=2i$ for which the residue is $res(f,2i) = e^{-2t}$. One then has that

$\oint_{\gamma} f(z)dz = \int_{\gamma_1}f(z)dz + \int_{\gamma_2} f(z)dz = 2\pi i \cdot res(f,2i)$

Showing that $\int_{\gamma_2} f(z)dz \rightarrow 0$ as $R\rightarrow \infty$, you arrive at

$\int_{\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{itz}}{z-2i} dz = 2\pi i e^{-2t}$

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice solution and (+1). If you enjoy nightmares, use algebra (what I did).

Comment: Thank you very much. I agree that using algebra for some cases is nightmares. Sometimes you have to use "genius" way to break the function down and compute. I got lots of troubles with that. Using complex analysis is a quick and easy way.

Comment: Thank you both. Happy to be of help.

Comment: The limit
\begin{equation*}
 \int_{\gamma_{2}}f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z \to 0 \text{ as } R\to \infty
\end{equation*}
is correct if $t>0$.

If $t<0$ you have to use a semicircle in the under half-plan. Then no singularity will be enclosed and the value of the given integral will be $0.$